# Unexpected Chrome Caching Issue in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, caching

In our MVC 4 web application we are using Areas and standard/default route configuration.  For example, if we want to view the notes/comments records for a particular customer we have a route that looks like:

```
/Customers/Notes/Index/123
```

Where we have a Controller named Notes in the 'Customers' area with an action method named 'Index'.  Our default routing would actually allow us to specify the same action as:

```
/Customers/Notes/123
```

For completeness, the Index action looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
     var model = UnitOfWork.CustomerDb
        .GetNotes(id);

     return View(model);
}
```

This result of this action is a simple data grid providing a chronological summary of the notes posted against a particular customer.  There's no AJAX or JSON involved.

This all works well - apart from when using Chrome.  This browser appears to cache the page and render a previous page.  Refreshing the browser does not correct the problem, but if I clear the browser cache and then refresh, the correct data is rendered.

I'm assuming that Chrome is ignoring the id parameter.  My questions are:

- Why does this only appear to be a problem with Chrome?
- Is this a known/common problem?
- Is there a recognised solution?

I have used this, what I thought was safe technique, across the whole web application and have to confess I am confused as to why this is happening.

Any information/advice would be much appreciated.